# Prove $\frac{tf(t)}{\int_0^t f(s)ds}\ge\frac{tg(t)}{\int_0^t g(s)ds}$ given $f(0)=g(0)=0, f'(0)\ge g'(0)\ge 0, f''(s)\ge g''(s)> 0$ for $s\in[0,t]$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, definite-integrals

I thought about a statement that is intuitively right, but doesn't know how to prove it. So could anyone help me with this: Say two second order differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ defined on $[0,t]$, satisfying
$f(0) = g(0) = 0$, $f'(0) \geq g'(0)\geq 0$ and $f''(s) \geq g''(s)> 0$ for $s\in[0,t]$. Then how to show that $$\frac{tf(t)}{\int_0^t f(s)ds}\geq \frac{tg(t)}{\int_0^t g(s)ds}$$

Intuitively, they are all positive monotonically increasing function, and $f$ is steeper than $g$. So the rectangle area $tf(t)$ over the area under the curve, which is the integral $\int_0^t f(s)ds$, should be larger than that of $g$.

Is this intuition right? If this is right, how to show it? Many thanks!

Comment: I believe that the statement fails, and you would need a condition like $f'(0)/f(t) \geq g'(0)/g(t)$ in order to make the statement work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f = g + h$.  So your assumptions are $g(0)=h(0) = 0$, $g'(0) \ge 0$,  $h'(0) \ge 0$, $g''(s) > 0$ and $h''(s) \ge 0$ for $s > 0$, and your desired
conclusion is equivalent to
$$ h(t) \int_0^t g(s)\; ds \ge g(t) \int_0^t h(t)\; dt \tag{1}$$
Actually let's assume $h''(s) > 0$, not just $\ge$.
Take any $g$ and $h$ satisfying the assumptions and with the two sides of (1) not equal.  Then if these are not a counterexample, just interchange $g$ and $h$ and you get a counterexample.

For example, with $g(s) = s^2$ and $h(s) = s^3$, (1) is $t^3/3 \ge t^3/4$
which is true,
but with $g(s)=s^3$ and $h(s)=s^2$, (1) is $t^3/4 \ge t^3/3$ which is false.
This corresponds to $f(s) = s^3+s^2$.

Answer (score 5):

**Counterexample:** Take $t = 1$ and define
$$
g(x) = x^2, \quad f(x) = 2x^2 - \frac 13 x^3.
$$
In particular, the ratios come out to
$$
\frac{tg(t)}{\int_0^tg(s)\,ds} = 3, \quad 
\frac{tf(t)}{\int_0^tf(s)\,ds} = \frac{2 - \frac 13}{\frac 23 - \frac 1{12}} = \frac{20}{7} < 3.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But ... Hmmm, this example does not satisfy the second derivative requirement $f''(s)\geq g''(s)$ on $s\in[0,t]$, isn't it? In your example, $f'' = 2$ and $g''(s) = 4-2s$, the former is smaller than the later on [0,1].

Comment: @Robert Sorry, I arranged things to go the wrong way. See my latest edit; I think things work correctly now

Comment: @Robert Actually, I just labelled them backwards. Edited again